# Javascript .slice method (a deeper understanding)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

I'm new to programming and I'm working on LearnStreet's *"Writing functions"*.
My question is with the following:

```
function capitalizeFirst(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}
```

I get that if it were only :

```
return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
```

only the first letter would be returned and capitalized, but why does adding `.slice(1)` give the whole string back?

In the case of:

```
capitalizeFirst("i am apple");
// "I am apple" is returned
```

but with

```
function capitalizeFirst(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(0); // 0 instead of 1
}

capitalizeFirst("i am apple");
// "Ii am apple" is returned
```

Thanks ahead of time for any help/guidance towards this question.

Comment: [Documentation for String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), not to be confused with [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion is natural. Almost every programmer makes an [off by one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) at some point in their life. So I'll explain it to you using examples:

Consider the string `"Hello World!"`. In a computer it would be represented in memory as an array of characters. It would look like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |   | W | o | r | l | d | ! |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
```

Now I want you to notice that there are only 12 boxes (characters), but 13 indices (`0` to `12`). The indices are in between the characters.

**Note:** The last index is always the length of the array.

A common mistake programmers make is that when they think of an array they think in terms of the boxes and not in terms of indices.

**Important:** An array is described in terms of its indices and not the number of boxes.

Now let's look at the `slice` method. This method takes two indices, the second one being optional. It returns a substring of the given string.

For example if I only wanted `"World"` from `"Hello World!"` I would extract it like this (`"World"` starts at index `6` and ends at index `11`):

```
"Hello World!".slice(6, 11); // "World"
```

If I wanted everything after the space in `"Hello World!"` (i.e. if I wanted `"World!"`) then I could use a short form instead of `slice(6, 12)`. Here the `12` is implied, so I can simply use `slice(6)`:

```
"Hello World!".slice(6); // "World!"
```

I could even use negative indices to extract say the last character of the string without knowing the length of the string:

```
"Hello World!".slice(-1); // "!"
```

The `-1` here represents the index `length - 1`. Since `length` is defined as the last index it's simply `12 - 1` in this case. Hence it returns everything after the index `11`.

**Understood?** So now you understand the fencepost problem.

This is why you get the entire string as it is when you call `slice(0)`; and you everything after the first character when you call `slice(1)`.

Always remember to think in terms of indices and not boxes when dealing with arrays.

**Read in between the characters.**

Comment: Thank so much Aadit for taking the time out to fully explain my problem. I understand it more completely now. I'll bang that into my head. "Think of indices" (= Again, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

`str.slice(x, y)` will return the characters of the string that are between index `x` and index `y`.
If you don't pass `y` (which you don't), it defaults to the end of the string.

Therefore, `str.slice(1)` will return all characters in the string starting from index `1`.
Since indexes are zero-based, that means everything but the first character.

Comment: ahhhh! I see thanks! charAt add the first letter, and .slice puts on the rest. Thanks SLaks (=

Answer (score 0):

slice(1) returns the rest of the string, everything after the first character.  So you get the whole string by adding together the first letter (capitalized) and the rest of the string.